# Can anyone show me how I can create a box like this?

Tags: color, box

I'm new to Latex and I need to make box that looks exactly like this. I've tried using tcolorbox but it just doesn't look the same as [image: desired result]

This is what I've had so far

```
 \documentclass[oneside]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \begin{document}
 \definecolor{main}{HTML}{5989cf}
 \definecolor{sub}{HTML}{cde4ff}
 \tcbset{sharp corners, colback = white, before skip = 0.2cm, after skip = 0.5cm }
 \newtcolorbox{boxH}{ colback = sub, colframe = main, boxrule = 0pt, leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight 
   }
 \begin{boxH}
   \textsf{\textbf{Claim}} -- We can prove. 
 \end{boxH}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black] 
   \textsf{\textbf{Claim}} -- We can prove $a<b$ 
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show the code of what you have tried?

Comment: This is what I've had so far
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{main}{HTML}{5989cf}
\definecolor{sub}{HTML}{cde4ff}
\tcbset{sharp corners,
colback = white,
before skip = 0.2cm,
after skip = 0.5cm
}
\newtcolorbox{boxH}{
colback = sub, 
colframe = main, 
boxrule = 0pt, 
leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight
}
\begin{boxH}
\textsf{\textbf{Claim}} -- We can prove.
\end{boxH}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
\textsf{\textbf{Claim}} -- We can prove $a<b$
\end{document}

Comment: I suggest that you update your question with that code snippet. Perhaps also by adding a picture of the result. That way, it will be easier for the helpers to see what is needed. Cheers!

Comment: @ngduchieu1903: Can you provide a more descriptive title to your question, rather than stating something similar to "How do I do this?" Provide an abridged description of the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{colorb}{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{green!50!black},
colback=green!05!white,
sharp corners
}

\begin{document}


\begin{colorb}
\textcolor{green!50!black}{\textbf{\textsf{Claim --}}} The only such function is $f(x)=0$.
\end{colorb}

\end{document}
```

[image]